# what is the minimum required to get spring mvc 3.1 to output json and xml response?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have included jackson mapper in my pom file

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

Also for xml I included both spring oxm and xstream in my pom file

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

         <dependency>
            <groupId>com.thoughtworks.xstream</groupId>
            <artifactId>xstream</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

And the follow is my spring mvc config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:oxm="http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm/spring-oxm-3.0.xsd">


    <mvc:resources mapping="/static/js/**" location="/static/js/"/>
    <mvc:resources mapping="/favicon.ico" location="/favicon.ico"/>

    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.xyz.web.controllers"/>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

And whenever I tried to get the json or xml response, I got this

```
 DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver - Resolving exception from handler [public com.xyz.web.controllers.User com.xyz.web.controllers.UserController.get(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)]: org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable representation
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: this post might be helpful 
http://blog.springsource.org/2010/01/25/ajax-simplifications-in-spring-3-0/

Comment: well, based on that post the json serialization "is enabled automatically when you use the mvc:annotation-driven configuration element with Jackson present in your classpath". I am sure I met both criteria.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Spring-Json-View](http://spring-json.sourceforge.net/), makes it very very easy to use `json` with `spring-mvc` and also has default support for `Xstream`

Answer (score 0):

What annotations do you have on the your controller methods.

I have the following and all is well:

```
@RequestMapping("carrierCompanies_json")
@ResponseBody
public Map<String, String> getValuesAsJSON() {
    return shipperService.getInfoForUser(getUser());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What I did is that:

I just added the jackson dependency to my pom file and then add @ResponseBody:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public Map<String, String> getTestValue() {
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("1", "dfd");
    map.put("2", "dfd");
    map.put("3", "dfd");
    map.put("4", "dfd");
    return map;
}
```

And then I got the expected result:
{
    "1": "dfd",
    "2": "dfd",
    "3": "dfd",
    "4": "dfd"
}

By the way, I use spring mvc 3.1.

Before I use spring mvc 3.1, I used 3.0 and when I did the above, I also had to add the following to the .xml file:

```
<beans:bean id="stringHttpMessageConverter"
    class="org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter" />

<beans:bean id="jsonHttpMessageConverter"
    class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter" />

<beans:bean id="methodHandlerExceptionResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerExceptionResolver">
    <beans:property name="messageConverters">
        <beans:list>
            <beans:ref bean="stringHttpMessageConverter" />
            <beans:ref bean="jsonHttpMessageConverter" />
        </beans:list>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>
```

I hope this helps you.